# VB net como enviar imagem q está em um user control para um form

Tags: vb.net, picturebox, usercontrol

Tenho uma picturebox em um User Control, e quero que ao clicar nela, a imagem da picturebox do use control vá para uma picturebox de um form, como fazer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não é difícil:

```
Public Sub PictureBox1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.Click
    ' Desabilita verificação cross-thread
    Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = False

    ' Altera no controle do Form
    Form1.PictureBox1.Image = PictureBox1.Image
    ' sendo Form1 o nome da sua form destino
End Sub
```

Se quiser que a imagem suma após isso, só colocar a linha `PictureBox1.Image = Nothing` no final das outras procedências.